# Instagram API recent media endpoint returning post URLs that can't be viewed

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Users in my web app authenticate with Instagram. After, I query `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/` to fetch recent posts and generate a preview of each using Instgram's oembed endpoint.

This works fine for 99% of my users so far, but now I see for one user, the recent posts endpoint is returning post links that can't be opened (I see same result when pasting URL into browser)

Also, it seems like the post link returned for this user are much longer than a usual Instagram URL like https://www.instagram.com/p/bNd86MSFv6/

What could be the reason for posts not being viewable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Longer URLs are usually photo links from private profile, so it will not be viewed by just anyone.

Comment: Thanks. Yes it seems the customer has set up a private account which would explain it